# need be more dynamic when using search function in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and is stuck when wondering how to make the search result more dynamic, that is after searching the "price", i need to copy the "price" and the cell at the right of it to cell A1, any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Find(What:="price", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("L14:M14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim f as Range
    Set f = Activesheet.Cells.Find(What:="price", After:=ActiveCell, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False
    if not f is nothing then
        f.resize(1,2).copy Activesheet.Range("a1")
    end if
End Sub
```